# Implementing join function in a user level thread library

Tags: c, multithreading, join

I am trying to implement a user level thread library as part of a project. My focus is on the join function. Lets say that Thread1 calls join function on Thread2. What i need to do is get the return value/argument supplied to pthread_exit() from Thread2 and store it in the memory location specified in join function argument.

But, how do i get the return value of another thread?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It depends entirely on how your implementation works. There is no generic/portable way to do "user level threads".

Comment: Yea, that is right. I am just looking for an idea to do this. I cannot think of any of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example taken from the [GnuPth](http://www.gnu.org/s/pth/)(`pth_lib.c`) user-level threading library, which shows the implementation of the `exit` and `join` functions, respectively. I **simplified** the code to highlight the return value handling.

```
void pth_exit(void *value)
{
    pth_debug2("pth_exit: marking thread \"%s\" as dead", pth_current->name);

    /* the main thread is special, because its termination
       would terminate the whole process, so we have to delay 
       its termination until it is really the last thread */

    /* execute cleanups */

    /*
     * Now mark the current thread as dead, explicitly switch into the
     * scheduler and let it reap the current thread structure; we can't
     * free it here, or we'd be running on a stack which malloc() regards
     * as free memory, which would be a somewhat perilous situation.
     */
    pth_current->join_arg = value;
    pth_current->state = PTH_STATE_DEAD;

    pth_debug2("pth_exit: switching from thread \"%s\" to scheduler", pth_current->name);

    //return (for ever) to the scheduler
}
```

and the corresponding `pth_join`:

```
/* waits for the termination of the specified thread */
int pth_join(pth_t tid, void **value)
{      
    //Validate thread situation.

    //wait until thread death

    //save returned value for the caller
    if (value != NULL)
        *value = tid->join_arg;

    //remove thread from the thread queue

    //free its memory space

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As i understand, u will not free the context associated with the thread in exit function. But, when do you actually do it? It can be done in join function, but what if the thread was never joined by any other thread. when does the freeing happen in this case?

Comment: yes, Gnupth (not me!) frees the thread data in the `join` function. As far as I remember (correct me if I'm wrong), the POSIX interface makes mandatory the `join` operation, unless a specific thread attribute is set. So you can add a hook in `exit` to release the memory in this particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could create storage for the return value in the application or process context, initialized when your threads library initializes. Your pthread_exit would fill the value and your join would use the threadid to retrieve it - I think this will only work for non-dynamically allocated return values though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interesting about the meta-info for individual thread in you implementation. Return value could be one of items stored in that of a thread, besides ID, stack pointer and so on.

When pthread_exit() is called, such information should be dumped to one or more data structures by scheduler, so that other thread can consult them when needed.

Comment: i cannot store it inside the thread's meta info ,right? because, i will have to free the info associated with the thread as soon as the thread exits.

Comment: No, for joinable threads you cannot free that meta info until the thread is joined. Otherwise (1) there's nowhere to store the return value, and (2) the same thread id could end up getting reused for a new thread.